# Bash scripting: If command returns nothing and user chooses to retry, repeat command

Tags: bash, while-loop, user-input

It may be a very simple problem that I'm facing but for the life of me I cannot find the right logic/syntax. I am trying to make this function work:

```
function ()
{

read -p "Enter pattern: " pattern

grep $pattern

if [ -z "$(grep $pattern)" ]; then

read -p "No results found. Do you want to retry with different pattern (y/n)? " yesno

if [ $yesno = y ]; then

function

fi

}
```

So basically  what I want is to:

1. prompt user for pattern;
2. after user enters pattern the grep command will search for that pattern;
3. if the pattern is not found therefore grep returns nothing, the user will be prompted to retry with a different pattern;
4. if the user chooses to retry, repeat the whole function

In the form I presented above, if the user chooses `y`, the function is repeated but even if grep finds something, it will loop infinitely, reprompting the user to enter a pattern etc.

I tried with:

```
while [ -z "$(grep $pattern)" ]

do

read -p "No results found. Do you want to retry with different pattern (y/n)? " yesno

if [ $yesno = y ]; then

function

else

break

fi

done
```

In this version, it almost works except for the fact that if the user chooses `y` 3 times to search for a different pattern and then chooses `n`, the `No results found. Do you want to retry with different pattern (y/n)?` prompt will repeat 3 times and only after that the function will exit.

I tried with `until [ -n "$(grep $pattern)" ]`, same results.

Comment: Note that your `grep` command is reading from standard input unless the user types more than one word as the pattern (in which case, it looks for the first word in the files named by the second and subsequent words).  In fact, you try to do `grep` twice.  And your code is syntactically incorrect; you are missing a `fi` from the first function.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the fi in the first function, I edited, it was correct in the script though. The user input will always be one word so no need to worry about that.

Comment: If this was to be a production script, you would have to worry about the user not typing one word. Programs break, or become targets for viruses, etc, because they don't take care to handle inputs correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a major problem with identifying the list of files that `grep` is searching. As it stands, the user types the material on standard input, and has to type <kbd>Control-D</kbd> to indicate EOF, then has to repeat the process for the second `grep`.  This is not plausible — I'm going to assume that you pass the list of files to be searched to the function as arguments (hence the `"$@"` on the `grep` command line).

The `grep` command returns status 0, success, when it finds the pattern in its inputs.  You can test this status directly.  This leads to:

```
function()
{
    while read -p "Enter pattern: " pattern
    do
        if grep "$pattern" "$@"
        then break  # Pattern found
        elif read -p "No results found. Do you want to retry with different pattern (y/n)? " yesno &&
             [ "$yesno" = 'y' ]
        then : OK - try again
        else break  # User did not type 'y'
        fi
    done
}
```

These loops should stop if the user indicates EOF in response to either prompt, which is basic good behaviour on part of a program.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now as intended. I thought of while-looping all the comands in the function but could not think of a valid syntax and I also assumed it is overkill and that I could do it by only looping part of the function. I didn't know that `if grep "$pattern" "file"` is equivalent with "if command returns 0". I also didn't know that it is possible to chain a `read` with a `[]` in a conditional. Could you please tell me what the `:` does in this case? Does it repeat the while-loop?

Comment: `:` is a command that does nothing successfully.  The arguments are evaluated, but that's all.  It was, once upon a very long time ago, the comment mechanism in Bourne shells (before there was a Bash).  You might occasionally find the odd ancient script that starts with `:` instead of `#!`; it was an indicator used to indicate that the script should be run by the Bourne shell instead of the C shell.